# how to add custom section in hybris product cockpit editor area

Tags: customization, sap-commerce-cloud, backoffice

I have tried below configuration,but it's not working.please let me know what       all the other things need to be done to make it work.

```html
<editor>
<custom-group class="de.hybris.platform.cockpit.services.config.impl.ClassAttrEditorSectionConfiguration" qualifier="New Section" initially-opened="false" visible="true">
<label>New Section<label/>
</custom-group>
</editor>
```

Answer (score 1):

To add a new **custom group** to the **cockpit** you need to follow some specific instructions.

1. First, in `[custom]cockpits\resources\[custom]cockpits-config\[custom_group]\editorArea_[custom_item].xml` add the following snippet :

**[custom_group]** : could be **admingroup** or **cockpitgroup** for example.
**[custom_item]** : could be **Product** or **MyProduct** or any other item.

For example : `mycockpits\resources\mycockpits-config\admingroup\editorArea_Product.xml`

```xml
<custom-group class="de.hybris.platform.cockpit.services.config.impl.ClassAttrEditorSectionConfiguration" qualifier="my_new_section" initially-opened="true" show-if-empty="true"  visible="true">

   <label lang="de">Section name [DE]</label>
   <label lang="en">Section name [EN]</label>
   <label lang="fr">Section name  [FR]</label>

</custom-group>
```

**class** : should be implementing `CustomEditorSectionConfiguration` and extending from `DefaultEditorSectionConfiguration`.
**qualifier** : should not contains blank space.

2. Run **Ant**, then execute the **update** from HAC with project data for the extension `mycockpits` is checked :

   [image]

Note : that the **update** it could be not necessary in some cases.

3. Finally, from`/productcockpit` reset the **personalized settings** :

   [image]

Then you should be able to see the new Section now.

Comment: Yes, I see this is how you create a new section. But how do you populate it with product attribute for example?? Doesn't seem to allow <property ... /> but only expecting <label>.

Answer (score 1):

The above explanation is very well written, but is this really what you want? You wrote something about "how to add custom SECTION".

So if you are talking about this stuff here:
[image]

If you want add stuff like this, you have to do things for example like here in the editorArea_xxx.xml file:

```html
 <group qualifier="admin" visible="true" initially-opened="false">
  <label key="config.general.administration" />
  <property qualifier="CMSItem.uid"/>
  <property qualifier="AbstractCMSComponent.slots"/>
  <property qualifier="AbstractCMSComponent.container"/>
  <property qualifier="Item.pk" />
  <property qualifier="Item.creationTime" />
  <property qualifier="Item.modifiedtime" />
 </group>
```

Than do the step 2) and 3) from Mouad EL Fakir answear.

BR